# Converting a string to integer in CSV import on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I've a rake task where I import CSV data into a database via Rails.

I want a specific column (specifically, row[6] below) to be rendered as an integer. However, everything I try returns that value as a string.

Below is the rake task:

```
require 'csv'
namespace :import_site_csv do
  task :create_sites => :environment do
    CSV.foreach('../sites.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
        row[6] = row[6].to_i
        Site.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

Does anyone have an idea how I might do this? Thanks!

Comment: What I realized (to my embarrassment) was that in the migration itself that created the table into which the data was being dumped, I specified there that the field row[6] populated was a string. Once I changed t.string to t.integer, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making one small (but important) mistake here.

When you call `CSV.foreach('../sites.csv')` each of the rows will be an array of the values in that particular row. That would allow you to access the data you need, in the way you do it now - `row[6]`.

*But*, when you add the `:headers => true` option to `CSV.foreach`, you will not get an array of values (`row` will not be an array). Instead, it will be a `CSV::Row` object ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html)). As you can read in the documentation:

> A CSV::Row is part Array and part Hash. It retains an order for the fields and allows duplicates just as an Array would, but also allows you to access fields by name just as you could if they were in a Hash.

For example, if you have a column with the name `Title` in the CSV, to get the title in each of the rows, you need to do something like:

```
CSV.foreach('file.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
    puts row['Title']
end
```

Since I do not know the structure of your CSV, I cannot tell you which key you should use to get the data and convert it to an Integer, but I think that this should give you a good idea of how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks, Ile! This is good information. Unfortunately, I'm still having the problem. I can access the value (row[6] or more specifically, row['trust_id']) and convert it to an integer initially. However, during the course of the Site.create!(row.to_hash), it converts the value back into a string. Do you have any idea why that would do that?

Comment: Absolutely! Here is a sample from the CSV file, which includes the header: `name,city,state,country,start_date,end_date,trust_id,site_code
MONKEY-SYSTEMs,CLEVELAND,OH,USA,1/2/1968,1/2/1968,1,ABEST-0481`

Comment: And below is code I tried afterward: `CSV.foreach('../sample_sites.csv', :headers => true) do |row|`
`row['trust_id'] = row['trust_id'].to_i` 
`puts(row['trust_id'].is_a? Integer)`
`Site.create!(row.to_hash)` The puts outputs true, signaling the value is an integer at that point, but then when Site.create runs, the value in the row is converted back to a string.

Comment: Actually, I just tested your code and it works. It returns the following: `{"name"=>"MONKEY-SYSTEMs", "city"=>"CLEVELAND", "state"=>"OH", "country"=>"USA", "start_date"=>"1/2/1968", "end_date"=>"1/2/1968", "trust_id"=>1, "site_code"=>"ABEST-0481"}`. I am not sure if you can spot it, but the `trust_id` is an integer (does not have the quotes around it). Could it be that you are having another issue, and not with the CSV?

Comment: I think I just figured it out. Thanks so much for your help! I owe you a beer next time I'm in Amsterdam!

Comment: Perfect! By the way, it would be helpful to update the question with the actual solution :)